# electron-builder change install directory on Windows

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I would like to change the install directory on Windows, my Electron App is built with [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder).

I've tried putting a `installer.nsh` file inside the build folder, but it's still the same, it always installs under the default path `AppData/Roaming/`.

This is my `installer.nsh`:

```
!macro preInit
 SetRegView 64
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\CustomPath"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\CustomPath"
 SetRegView 32
  WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\CustomPath"
  WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "C:\CustomPath"
!macroend
```

Has anyone managed to change the default install directory with electron-builder?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your target a one-click installer or an assisted installer with changeable installation directory?

Comment: I am using a oneclick installer i think. I have `target:["nsis"]`

Comment: The above code is taken from [the docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#common-questions), I found this broke my uninstaller.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this question. Putting the `installer.nsh` inside the `build` folder is the first part. The second part, you need to tell the installer to look for it. Under `nsis` see the last line: `"include": "build/installer.nsh"`

```
  ...
  "nsis": {
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
    "oneClick": false,
    "license": "license.html",
    "include": "build/installer.nsh"
  },
  ...
```

That did the trick for me.